# Перестал работать экспорт Диаграмм в excel, VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, диаграммы

Для своей программы мне понадобилось сделать создание диаграммы в листе Excel, затем экспорт этой диаграммы в .gif картинку, а затем вставка этой картинки на мою форму. В принципе всё получилось, всё работает, но вчера когда игрался с формой вылетела ошибка
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
"Method 'Export' of Object '_Chart' Failed"

Код где возникает ошибка:

```
    'Скачиваем и закачиваем диаграмму
    Sub exportAndLoadDiagram(uf As EarthForm)
        
        Dim CurrentFileName As String
        CurrentFileName = Workbooks("Проект.xlsm").Path & "/current.gif"
         
        Dim MyChart As Chart
        Set MyChart = Workbooks("Проект.xlsm").Worksheets("Диаграмма грунтов пикета").ChartObjects("EarthOnPicketDiagram").Chart
        'Ошибка вот здесь
        MyChart.Export CurrentFileName, "GIF"
         
        uf.Image_earthOnPicket.Picture = LoadPicture(CurrentFileName)
        '=====================
         
        'Удаляем с листа диаграмму
        Workbooks("Проект.xlsm").Worksheets("Диаграмма грунтов пикета").Shapes("EarthOnPicketDiagram").Delete
    End Sub
```

И самое интересное, что эта ошибка случается через раз. Иногда может случиться, а иногда нет. Полазив в интернете я увидел, что такая ошибка у людей с 2003+ года. Но толкового решения не нашёл. Может быть его и нету..
Может есть решение? Или подскажет кто-нибудь каким альтернативным способом можно экспортировать диаграмму в форму?

Comment: Ошибка не воспроизводится. Попробуйте очищать буфер, сохранять в .jpg, перед вставкой закрывать/открывать  форму... Создайте и прикрепите тестовый файл. Кстати, часто бывает, что проблема локализуется при подготовке примера

Comment: В этом и суть, у меня тоже работает (несколько раз), но в какой-то определенный момент выскакивает ошибка.

Comment: Будете и дальше рассказывать об ошибке или поработаете над примером? Я набросал пример, с формой, ошибки не было НИ РАЗУ... Хотя форма там и не нужна, ведь ошибка сохранения файла... Создаем книгу, в ней простейшую диаграмму., прописываем там макрос. Дальше по ситуации: ошибки нет - приближайте пример к рабочему файлу; ошибка есть - упрощаем макрос. Ошибка воспроизводится на простейшем примере - прикрепите, другие проверят вашу книгу...

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал. В коде всё лишнее опустил и оставил только самое главное. Ошибка теперь появляется сразу. Скажите, как и куда я могу загрузить книгу excel, чтобы вам и другим пользователям было удобно посмотреть код?

Comment: На любой файлообменник. И показать ссылку

Comment: Доброго времени суток, добавил книгу на DropMeFiles. Вот ссылка dropmefiles.com/IuiSN Заметил одну особенность: если в модуле Module1 за комментировать строчку Убираем границу фигуры ch.Line.Visible = msoFalse, то тогда ошибка пропадает. Как это может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

Замените свой код на этот (в *UserForm* заменить вызов на *Main_*):

```
Option Explicit

Sub openme(): UserForm1.Show: End Sub

Sub Main_()
    Dim dataTable As ListObject
    Const chartName As String = "EarthOnPicketDiagram"

    Set dataTable = Worksheets("Лист1").ListObjects("TableForDiagram")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Call drawChart(chartName, dataTable)
    Call exportAndLoadDiagram(chartName)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub drawChart(chartName As String, dataTable As ListObject)
    Dim chart_ As Shape
    
    Set chart_ = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
    
    With chart_
        .Select
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xl3DColumnClustered
        .Name = chartName
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        
        With .Chart
            .SetSourceData Range(dataTable), PlotBy:=xlRows
            .SetElement (msoElementDataLabelShow)
            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone)
            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesNone)
            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisNone)
            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisNone)
            .SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
            .Axes(xlValue).ReversePlotOrder = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Грунты пикета №"
            .Floor.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub exportAndLoadDiagram(chartName As String)
    Dim chart_ As Chart
    Dim fileName As String
    
    fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/current.gif"
    Set chart_ = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName).Chart

    chart_.Export fileName, "GIF"
    UserForm1.Image_earthOnPicket.Picture = LoadPicture(fileName)

    ActiveSheet.Shapes(chartName).Delete
End Sub
```

Нужно ли каждый раз создавать-удалять диаграмму? В книге в укромном месте оставить отформатированную заготовку и только менять там исходные данные (если вообще нужно менять диапазон). Код сократится на 35-40%